# RC Bandpass Filter on pspice :unity gain frequency

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image: Here is the my circuit design for those who asked.]I am simulating a pspice bandpass RC filter by cascading 2 opamps one HP and one LP. I am getting this bode plot at the end. Is the unity gain frequency the 2 frequencies at 0 dB?

[image]

Comment: Hi. I think the concept and term “unity gain frequency” is not appropriate here. That is something having to do with feedback circuits. For filters, usually the important things are “gain”and “bandwidth”. Asking about these things makes more sense here.

Comment: @Nick exactly, but that was what was instructed for me by my teacher. I guess he wanted the frequencies for where the amplifier acts as a buffer amplifier for power rather than actually amplifying the voltage.